# Python - stop a while loop in a method based on attribute change

Tags: python, loops, oop

I have a very simple class with one attribute and one method. i would like the method to run based on the value of the attribute. below is the class code:

```
class TestWhile()
   def __init__(self):
      self.status = "OFF"
   def StreamV(self):
      while self.Status == "ON"
         print "nonstop"
```

basically what I want to do is set Status to ON, then run StreamV until Status is set to off. This is what i want as follows:

```
P = TestWhile()
T.Status = "ON"
T.StreamV()
T.Status = "OFF"
```

When I run the above test, it never makes it to the Status = "OFF" line and infinitely runs the loop. How can I fix this?

Comment: y'all need [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) up in here

Comment: Unless you make a way for the while loop to turn `self.Sstatus = 'OFF'` you might need to do threading.

Comment: How can i do threading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your call to `T.StreamV()` does what is commonly referred to as [Busy looping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) and blocks the main thread. What you have effectively described you want is a background thread to update some value until a signal comes in (from your `T.Status` attribute)

Threading is relatively approachable for simple problems, and is an incredibly useful tool to get to know. From a super wide viewpoint a thread in python is a function that can run at the same time the main script is doing something else. In this regard python threads are indeed created by passing them a function to execute.

Example:

```python
import threading
import time

class TestWhile(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.status = "OFF"
        self.streamVthread = threading.Thread(target=self.StreamV) #create a thread for our streamV function
    def StreamV(self):
        print "starting thread"
        while self.Status == "ON":
            print "nonstop"
            time.sleep(1)
        print "stopping thread"

T = TestWhile() #our thread is actually created here, but is hasn't started yet
print 'T.Status -> "ON"'
T.Status = "ON"  #T.StreamV could be modified to run at creation and wait for this to change to "ON"
T.streamVthread.start() #this calls the T.StreamV function in a separate thread
time.sleep(6)
T.Status = "OFF"
print 'T.Status -> "OFF"'
```

I've added a bunch of print statements to help you understand the flow of the program. Please comment with any questions.

**Edit: passing arguments to a thread**

Threads exist in the same namespace as the main thread, so if they share a variable with the main script they will both have access to it. This can cause problems with multiple threads accessing the same thing at the same time (read more on [locks and other mutex constructs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science))). Passing arguments at creation of the thread however can be done as such:

```python
import threading
import time

def sayHello(after_secs, name):
    time.sleep(after_secs)
    print("hello from {}".format(name))

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=sayHello, args=(3,"thread1"))
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=sayHello, args=(1,"thread2"))
thread3 = threading.Thread(target=sayHello, args=(5,"thread3"))

print "starting thread1"
thread1.start()
print "starting thread2"
thread2.start()
print "starting thread3"
thread3.start()


thread1.join() #wait for thread1 to finish
print "thread1 is done"
thread2.join() #wait for thread2 to finish
print "thread2 is done"
thread3.join() #wait for thread3 to finish
print "thread3 is done"
```

See if you can determine why these print statements happen in the order they do..

Comment: looks like what i need to do, however i cannot test until i get to my PC with Python on it. One question i had though was, what if i wanted to pass arguments to  StreamV? How would the thread change?

Comment: In the first example you can see that the thread has access to the same `T.Status` the main script does, but that's equivelent to using a Global: useful in some cases, but can get messy fast. See my edit for passing explicit variables to the called function in the thread